# How to re-activate scroll after exiting modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

How could I re-activate scroll after exiting the modal?

http://1ne-studio.com/test2/index.html
id   : test
pass : 2015

There is a link that turns modal on at the top-right corner of the grey sub-header.

I disabled the scroll on `body` when modal is open by adding class on the body

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#modal-name").mouseenter(function(){
       $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
       $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
         $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
            $("body").attr("overflow", "auto");
       $("body").focus();
    });
</script>
```

and disabling the parallax scroll in `fsvs.js` (controls the slideDown and Up)

```
slideDown : function(e) {
    if ($("body").hasClass("modal-open")) { return false; }
    if( app.canSlideDown() ) {
        ignoreHashChange = true;
        app.slideToIndex( (currentSlideIndex+1), e );
    } else {
        scrolling = false;
    }
},

/**
 * [slideUp description]
 * @return {[type]} [description]
 */

slideUp : function(e) {
    if ($("body").hasClass("modal-open")) { return false; }
    if( app.canSlideUp() ) {
        ignoreHashChange = true;
        app.slideToIndex( (currentSlideIndex-1), e );
    } else {
        scrolling = false;
    }
},
```

But after I exit from modal, scroll will not turn back on..

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: On your website, how do you exit from modal?

Comment: Try adding 'overflow:auto' for body while exiting the modal.

Comment: @AlexPan either you click the black background or click "閉じる" button at the top-right corner of the mordal.

Comment: It would be better for you to post your code here since your site is password protected. Also the question/answer becomes useful for someone else.

Comment: Thanks @EternalHour. I added code in this question.

Comment: It's not the modal. Scroll doesn't work to begin with because on line 7 of style.css `html` is given `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: You might be right.
Another problem is that I made it so that overflow:hidden will be applied when modal is opened so that background behind modal wont move when I am scrolling the content with in modal.

I also wrote in line 238 that after the mouse leaves modal, it will remove the class modal-open so that it will also removes the overflow:hidden; in line7.

but i guess its not working for some reason???

Comment: I fixed that overflow:hidden problem but the scroll is still not working...

Comment: Two things I notice - the same style is still applied to `html` for some reason (caching?) and you might want to wrap the script you added to the bottom of the page in a `$(document).ready( ...`.

Comment: thanks, i dont see overflow:hidden anymore from my side. I wrapped script with the one you suggested.. but still the same... :(

I need this to be done with in few more hours ....orz

Comment: Sorry, misdirect. Overflow on `html` doesn't seem to be too relevant (although it should solve the issue, it will be with a scrollbar). Not always easy to see how all of it is supposed to come together. Strange thing is that as soon as I open developer tools, the parallax works. But not when the page is initially loaded. Last suggestion I can offer, trigger an 'empty' resizing : `$(window).trigger('resize')`. Can't test if that actually works because I would have to open the inspector to run it (and can't see the issue then).

Comment: @Shikkediel What you are saying is right. parallax is being pain in the ass right now... I tried your suggestion but still the same... Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a answer..!

I took a closer look at the problem and found a solution to this.
This is not the best solution since I haven't really found a solution to the actual problem causing this.. But this did give me the result that I wanted.

I found out that, after exiting the modal, there's one way to fix this parallax and it was clicking the pagenation button on the right.

So I created

```
             var e = new jQuery.Event("click");
        e.offsetX = 100;
        e.offsetY = 100;
        $('#fsvs-pagination li.active').trigger(e);
```

which will make browser think that I clicked the pagenation button and will re-activate the parallax.

I have not yet checked every browser but this probably solved the issue.

Thank you for all of your support and please let me know if you have found a better solution.